# How to close a jdbc connection created through Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I've built an application (app1) that looks at and records certain fields in a database. This application shares the database with another application (app2) that requires a solitary connection to it when starting up but is fine to allow other connections to the DB once it (app2) is started. In my application (app1), I have made a dao object using Spring to connect to the DB and evidently, the connection is never closed which causes app2 to crash upon start up. From what I've read, Spring is supposed to automatically handle opening and closing all of the DB connections it manages. I'm not sure of any code I could share to help paint a better picture of my problem but if some is needed, I'll post what I can. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Spring will close its connections, but if you have a connection pool, the pool probably keeps the actual physical connection open to the database.

Comment: I'm thinking that's what I need closed, where/how would I do that?

Comment: That will depend on the particular server/connection pool you're using. It may have a setting to force the physical connection closed after every use. Note that this would degrade your application's performance.

Comment: Do you have the destroy-method attribute in your jdbc template bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the JDBC template you don't have to worry about explicitly closing connections, Spring will take care of internally managing a connection pool and obtaining/releasing connections from that pool.

Comment: If Spring keeps the connection alive in the pool as GriffeyDog said, can I go in and close it somehow?

Comment: why would you do that, then what is purpose of connection pool.

Comment: @lancex you seem to misunderstand the usage of a connection pool - the idea is _precisely_ to keep the connections open and never close them, only "releasing" them for future use. In this way you don't have to pay the price of reestablishing a connection over and over again.

Comment: You're right, I don't quite understand the usage of it. If it really is using a connection pool in the way you describe, would it still cause app2 to see an open connection and then fail?

Comment: @lancex I don't know the specifics of your environment, do both applications use Spring? do they use the same template configuration? is the pool correctly configured? does it define enough database connections to service both applications?

Comment: I don't believe app2 uses Spring, it was developed by a third party a long time ago. I technically do have access to a config file to force it to start whether it has the only connection or not but my superiors tell me they would much rather have my connection closed if possible. I can basically consider any configuration for app2 off-limits :/

Comment: @lancex the only thing I can think of that causes app2 to fail because it can't obtain a connection, would be that app1 is exhausting _all_ available connections in the database, I'd cross-check the database's configured max number of connections against spring's max number of connections. There should be a couple of spare connections left in the database for use by another applications, like app2

Comment: @lancex If this answer was helpful for you in any way, please don't forget to accept it ;)

Comment: Well, I know app1 is only taking up one connection and that after app2 starts up, everything is fine. The problem, I think, is that app2 wants to have the _only_ connection to the DB during start up and Spring still has the connection from app1 open to it. Think I'm on the right track here?

Comment: @lancex I doubt that app1 is taking only _one_ connection, you should check spring's pool configuration. And anyway, make sure that there are enough connections configured in the db to serve both app1's pool and app2's single connection and a couple more to spare (for admin consoles, etc.)

Comment: The thing is, SQL Server Management Studio only shows one connection for app1 and when I tell it to end the connection, app2 starts fine. I then bring up app1 and everything is running as it should :/ I guess I'll start googling all about how to configure Spring's connection pool... EDIT: I actually don't even need to restart app1, it reconnects all by itself after app2 is up.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing connections between applications I would recommend using a connection pool. Opening and closing of connections could be done by declarative transaction demarcation via annotations (@Transactional).

http://faheemsohail.com/2012/01/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you?

```
 public  void closeCon() {

  {
   if (con != null)
    try {
     con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```